# DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: chrome-extension

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome

A week ago i think, I started getting warning messages in my google chrome console.

[image: messages]
Clearing cache doesn't change anything, the messages disappear only in incognito mode.

Any ideas how to get rid of these warnings ?

Comment: Try: F12 > Application > Clear storage > Clear site data

Comment: @Ploppy messages are still there after F12 > Application > Clear storage > Clear site data

Comment: Some more info here https://superuser.com/questions/1523427/google-chrome-devtools-failed-to-parse-sourcemap-chrome-extension and a bug report here https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1052872

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I had this problem with the **LastPass** browser extension. I proved my theory by disabling **LastPass** and reloading the site in question - the warnings were gone!

I really didn't want to disable the JavaScript and CSS source maps so I have made the following change below:

Pending an update from the LastPass that addresses the issue, I have temporarily fixed this by changing one of the settings in the Extension settings for LastPass.

I had this setting previously set to **On all sites**, which was injecting the LastPass code on all sites blindly. With this change you need to right click on the **Username/Password** box to enable last pass, but on the plus side there are no warnings in the console anymore.

I consider this a temporary workaround until either Google or LastPass fix the issue.

---

EDIT: There is also a checkbox in the settings dialogue for the Console tab itself called **Selected context only**. Ticking this will remove the warnings and errors from Chrome extensions. Note this setting is not persisted - you'll have to click it each time you open the Dev Tools.

[image: Screenshot of the Console settings panel]

Answer (score 20):

I've just used Chrome Console Filter `-chrome-extension`. I see everything except **chrome-extension** output.

[image: Chrome Console Filter]

Comment: nicely explained [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/log#filter)

Comment: and even better than the accepted answer, the filter stays, so when you close and reopen they are still filtered out

Comment: Still don't know why Lastpass doesn't fix this. Being a dev requires using vault and these don't help when debugging is happening. :(

Answer (score 2):

For me it was the McAffee Web Advisor Chrome extension - removed and messages gone :)

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

1. Find the path to the extensions. Type this in chrome: chrome://version/ . Look for the profile path. this location is where the extensions are saved.
2. Open the location with the file explorer. In my case it was something like (AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd\4.51.0.1_0) The error was with the last pass plugin.
3. Create the missing maps. In my case it was: sourcemaps/

Note that i only created the empty maps.

Comment: where did you create empty maps? can you elaborate more on this, I am also facing the same issue

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Maybe useful for other users. where did you create empty maps? (you asked) That depends per user. In my case the extension (LastPass) was looking for a not existing folder "sourcemaps". So what i did was find the location where the extensions are installed. So via chrome://version/  you will see the profile path. If you open that location (with the file explorer) then you will see a folder named "Extensions" here is where the extensions are installed and where the missing files are. Like i said, this depends on the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

All I did is disable my LastPass extension(plugin), clear browsing data, hard reload the page and it works fine.
It might be another plugin for you

Answer (score -5):

You need to open settings from the debug console

[image: Open settings console in Chrome]

Then you disable one of chrome's option (They added it recently)

[image: Disable Chrome option]

Just refresh the browser and all ready

Comment: this will disable source map parsing completely, which is not acceptable for modern JS development process

Comment: @Erick I think that we need a solution to resolve this issue not just to hide the messages